# Internal Server Error (500) - Key must be a string or an entity table in POST request with Bearer token authorization

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I am encountering an issue with a POST request in my application. The request is made to https://my_domain:8443//post/action, and it requires authorization using a Bearer token.

My route request "http://localhost:8000/post/action"

I have implemented a JWT plugin to handle the Bearer token and ensure it is passed as a header. However, I am consistently receiving a 500 Internal Server Error with the message "Key must be a string or an entity table."

Can anyone provide insights into what might be causing this error and suggest potential fixes? I appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

I tried to check handler.lua code and I tried different ways of configuration but those aren't working

Comment: From your limited description, this might be coming from the `:cache_key` method of the custom entity DAO's; as the error message indicates, check if your key is a string or a table. Please add more information to your future questions -- I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Welcome to Stackoverflow! : )